# Cannot see controls in WPF window after applying style/template to Window

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, styles

I have a custom template for my application Windows that I have built. It's in App.xaml

```
<Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <Style x:Key="XWindow" TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate  >
                            <Border BorderThickness="3">
                                <Border.Effect>
                                    <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="5" Direction="270" RenderingBias="Quality" ShadowDepth="0.5" Opacity="0.8" Color="#FF00B9FF"/>
                                </Border.Effect>
                                <Grid Background="White">
                                    <local:ControlButtons Height="38" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
                                    <Border BorderBrush="#99007CF7" BorderThickness="1"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </Border>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
```

In my MainWindow.xaml I have applied this style like this (and it works) :  `<Window [...] Style="{DynamicResource XWindow }"`

So the style is applied to the window. But when I put a control in the Window, I cannot see it or even select it. It's in the XAML code but even when I debug it's not on the Window.. Anyone has a clue ?

There's a screenshot :
[XAML Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IAvfp.gif)

This is what it should normally do when I add a simple button : [XAML Norrmal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/awBO4.gif)

Comment: There should be a ContentPresenter in the Template, which shows the Window's actual Content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by @Clemens you have forgotten to add a `ContentPresenter` to your `ControlTemplate`. This is where the actual content of the window will be displayed.

You should also remember to put the `ContentPresenter` in an `AdornedDecorator`:

```
<Style x:Key="XWindow" TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
                <Border BorderThickness="3">
                    <Border.Effect>
                        <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="5" Direction="270" RenderingBias="Quality" ShadowDepth="0.5" Opacity="0.8" Color="#FF00B9FF"/>
                    </Border.Effect>
                    <Grid Background="White">
                        <local:ControlButtons Height="38" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
                        <Border BorderBrush="#99007CF7" BorderThickness="1">
                            <AdornerDecorator>
                                <ContentPresenter/>
                            </AdornerDecorator>
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

The `AdornedDecorator` specifies the position of the AdornerLayer in the visual tree as stated on MSDN here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.adornerdecorator.aspx. You will for example need one if you intend to dipslay any validation errors in your window as validation errors are displayed on the adorner layer.

**Edit:** You should also set the `TargetType` property of the `ControlTemplate`:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
```

Comment: See my edit. You should also set the TargetType property of the ControlTemplate.